# Create item- item Interaction Matrix in Pyspark

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataset containing two columns, user_id and item_id. The DataFrame looks like this:

```
index user_id item_id
0     user1   A
1     user1   B
2     user2   A
3     user3   B
4     user4   C
```

I'm looking for a way to transform this table into an item-item interaction matrix where we have **distinct intersection of common users** between items:

```
       A   B   C
A      2   1   0
B      1   2   0
C      0   0   1
```

And another item-item interaction matrix where we have **distinct union of users** between items:

```
       A   B   C
A      2   3   3
B      3   2   3
C      3   3   1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 0. Define the dataframe

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

data = [(0,     "user1",   "A"),
        (1,     "user1",   "B"),
        (2,     "user2",   "A"),
        (3,     "user3",   "B"),
        (4,     "user4",   "C")]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema=["index", "user_id", "item_id"])
```

Step 1. Collect user data for each item in df_collect

```
df_collect = (df
        .select("user_id", "item_id")
        .groupBy("item_id")
        .agg(F.collect_set("user_id").alias("users")))
```

Step 2. Cross join df_collect with itself to get all item-item combinations

```
df_crossjoin = (df_collect
                    .join(df_collect
                            .withColumnRenamed("item_id", "item_y")
                            .withColumnRenamed("users", "users_y")))
```

Step 2. Find user union and intersection and the count

```
df_ui = (df_crossjoin
                 .withColumn("users_union", 
                         F.size((F.array_union("users", "users_y"))))
                 .withColumn("users_intersect", 
                             F.size(F.array_intersect("users", "users_y"))))
```

Step 3. Pivot to get item-item matrix

```
df_matrix_union = (df_ui
                   .groupBy("item_id")
                   .pivot("item_y")
                   .agg(F.first("users_union"))
                   .orderBy("item_id"))

df_matrix_intrsct = (df_ui
                   .groupBy("item_id")
                   .pivot("item_y")
                   .agg(F.first("users_intersect"))
                   .orderBy("item_id"))
```

Comment: Hi Anna, this worked perfectly for a smaller dataset. But for dataset with 10million+ rows it is throwing error :
WARN Utils: Truncated the string representation of a plan since it was too large. This behavior can be adjusted by setting 'spark.debug.maxToStringFields' in SparkEnv.conf. Even after adjusting it to 1 million it throws error.

Comment: if  the plan is too large, maybe you can try to cache some intermediate results.